# json_decode and memory clear

Tags: php, memory

I have a list of large JSON files (smallest files are 500 Ko and biggest are 100 Mo).

I need to process each file independently. My problem is that the memory usage is growing more and more after each file, even if I clear all the memory.

Example:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    json_decode(file_get_contents($file->getRealpath()), true);

    $memory = memory_get_usage(true);
    echo 'Memory: '.@round($memory / pow(1024,($i=floor(log($memory, 1024)))), 2).' '.['b', 'kb', 'mb', 'gb', 'tb', 'pb'][$i]."\n";

    gc_collect_cycles();
}
```

Result:

```
Memory: 6 mb
(...)
Memory: 6 mb
Memory: 6 mb
Memory: 10 mb
Memory: 10 mb
Memory: 10 mb
(...)
Memory: 12 mb
Memory: 12 mb
Memory: 12 mb
(...)
Memory: 490 mb
Memory: 490 mb
Memory: 490 mb
(...)
Memory: 946 mb
Memory: 944 mb
Memory: 944 mb
(...)
```

Memory is growing more and more until PHP tells me he can't get more. As you can see I'm doing nothing in this example except a json_decode(), no variable assigned or whatever else. So why is my memory growing like this, and how can I clear it?

Comment: Just guessing, have you tried saving the json_decode to a variable or var_dump it. Not sure if the garbage collector will collect the void function.

Comment: I would not try to store the contents of a 100MB file in memory in the first place. Use a streaming JSON parser instead.

Comment: @MarcusNordin Yeah I tried it, this example is a simplified version of my code just to reproduce the problem : each call of json_decode on a file seems to take more and more memory, with no way to clear it.

Comment: @RaphaëlMalié Okay, that is very weird.... What PHP version are you using?

Comment: Maybe related to this:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79504

Answer (score 1):

Check the size of the file you are trying to get contents. That could be larger so it costs memory usage

Or

You need to check the which variable holds excessive memory, you can use `strlen()` it does not give you exact memory held by var but length is helpful to find the approximate value.

And you should `unset` the unused variables to clear the memory.

```
unset($decoded_data);
```

Or set

`$var = null`

When you are using unset, the memory will only be freed whenever garbage collector decides, but when you are setting a variable to a different value (null in this case), then you might get some memory freed of course with the cost of CPU.

I will recommend you to use

https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser

> This is a simple, streaming parser for processing large JSON
>   documents. Use it for parsing very large JSON documents to avoid
>   loading the entire thing into memory, which is how just about every
>   other JSON parser for PHP works.

Comment: I do not fill any variable in my example, so I have nothing to unset, and the memory usage is still growing. Even if I assign that content to a variable and unset it, it still grows.

Comment: are you sure you are not opening any big files? because you know well json decode holds the memory while you de code.

Comment: Does this happen when you json decode 10 files all same size (1MB)?